# How to freeze/grayish window in pygtk?

Tags: python, window, pygtk, freeze

I want main window to "gray, freeze, stop working", when some other window is opened. Is there some default way to do it? Pretty much the same as gtk.Dialog is working.

**EDIT:** Currently I'm just replacing all contents by a text line, but I guess there should be better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't try to make a program become unresponsive.
If what you want to do is stop the user from using the window, make the dialog modal: `gtk.Dialog.set_modal(True)`

Comment: Ah, I just figured it out. The window that should be active should be set to modal, yes. Too bad GTK really has some wierd way of naming functions.